# Make array unique

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make pipe delimited cell values in a column unique

Example

if cell value of D3 = Aa Bb|HH|Aa Bb|HH

then after running arrMakeUnique_n() the cell value of D3 = Aa Bb|HH

And this works, but if cell value of D2 is the same as D3 then only cell value of D3 is made unique D2 is unchanged

i.e

If there are multiple cells with the same value only one cell is made unique the others remain unchanged

I can not get why, any help is appriciated

Thanks

```
function arrMakeUnique_n() {

 arrMakeUnique(
  'sheet1',
  ["Header"], 
  "|",
  "|"
  );
}

function arrMakeUnique(shtName,cheaders, dilm1, dilm2) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shtName);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rangeValues = range.getValues();
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();

  var hn =[];
  var fhn = [];
  for (var k = 0; k <= cheaders.length-1; k++) { 
       //Get column indexes from headers
       hn[k] = HTN(shtName,cheaders[k]) - 1; 
  } 

  for (var j = 0; j <= cheaders.length-1; j++) {
    var frRange = sheet.getRange(2, hn[j]+1, LR-1, 1); 
    var frValues = frRange.getValues(); 

    // iterate through all cells in the selected range
   for (var cellRow = 1; cellRow < LR; cellRow++) {

        //Make array with split on | get unique with .getUnique() then Join with |
        //Logger.log((rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(frValues[cellRow]+dilm1)).getUnique().join(frValues[cellRow]+dilm2).trim())
        rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = (rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(frValues[cellRow]+dilm1)).getUnique().join(frValues[cellRow]+dilm2).trim();       
    }
  } 
  // Write back all values at once
  range.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

Edit: It turns out that using: `.getUnique` caused strange behavior in that it interfered with other scripts that were independent of its use.  xyz solution worked great luckily

```
//Make array unique
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}


function HTN(shtName,cheader){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(cheader);
  return colindex+1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another method:

```
function removeDuplicateFromDilmStr_n() {
var t="Abb Baa|HHH|Abb Baa"
Logger.log(removeDuplicateFromDilmStr(t,"|", "|"))
}

function removeDuplicateFromDilmStr(str, dilm1, dilm2){
var arr = str.toString().split(dilm1)
var outArray = [];

arr.sort(lowerCase);
function lowerCase(a,b){
return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
}
var unique_array = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
});

unique_array = unique_array.join(dilm2).trim();

return unique_array
}
```

And then change this:

```
rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = (rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(frValues[cellRow]+dilm1)).getUnique().join(frValues[cellRow]+dilm2).trim();
```

to this:

```
rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = removeDuplicateFromDilmStr(rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]], "|","|");
```

Comment: It turned out that the use of `getUnique` caused internal issues in Google sheets with other independent scrips` so I stopped using it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to script this? The following formula using native [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) functions works fine.

```
=join("|", unique(transpose(split(D3, "|", false, true))))
```

Perhaps it would be easier to insert a column, run that formula down then revert the results to values and delete the original column (in script or not).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I do need it scripted

Comment: Well, that's how to perform the action; just reproduce the functions in script. They are are all there, I guarantee it.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array merge function (you will also find this very useful for other use cases):

```
function deDupe(){
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("D3").setValue(merge(sheet.getRange("D3").getValue().split("|")));
  //In your scenario only D3 is modified, but I think you forgot to ask, if D3 and D2 are different AFTER the code runs, then set them equal.
  if (sheet.getRange("D3").getValue()!=sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()){
    sheet.getRange("D2").setValue(sheet.getRange("D3").getValue());
    //Or do something different
  }
}


function merge(a1, a2) {
  var hash = {};
  var arr = [];
  var target = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (hash[a1[i]] !== true) {
      target = a1[i].trim();
      if (target.length>0) {
        hash[target] = true;
        arr[arr.length] = target;
      }
    }
  }
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
      if (hash[a2[i]] !== true) {
        target = a2[i].trim();
        if (target.length>0) {
          hash[target] = true;
          arr[arr.length] = target;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Note that I am passing only one array to merge. It actually works identically if you pass the same array twice, but obviously will take more time.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = (rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(frValues[cellRow]+dilm1)).getUnique().join(frValues[cellRow]+dilm2).trim();
```

to this

```
rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(dilm1).getUnique().join(dilm2).trim();
```

Also, if you want to sort the cell value

```
//Make array unique
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, arr = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      arr.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }

  arr.sort(lowerCase);
  function lowerCase(a,b){
    return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
  }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Einarr. It turned out that the use of `getUnique` caused internal issues in Google sheets with other independent scrips` so I stopped using it.  But you saved the day with how to rewrite the loop

Comment: @user777 adding to the array prototype is going to cause issues if you are enumerating the array instead of iterating it. A quick Google search about `Array` and `for... in`   with JavaScript will help you understand the issue.